# Where should I ask questions about diving?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

Not long a got I finished my course, and I'm excited to get started (Scuba diving and free diving). And now I have questions like:

- What equipments is better for __?
- How can I reduce amount of air I use during the dive?

I have looked at [Sports](https://sports.stackexchange.com/), [Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) and [Physical Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/). Somehow seems to me that each almost fits, but not really. So is there an SE site that suits this kind of questions? (and has hopefully some people to answer)

Comment: You can always help in the definition of this proposal http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54313/scuba-diving

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What equipments is better for __?

This sort of question is pretty much off topic network wide, see [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

As for the second one, [Sports.SE](https://sports.stackexchange.com/) seems to be the best bet as they do have [a well answered question on scuba diving](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/is-a-too-low-ascent-speed-unsafe)

If you would like a dedicated site for Scuba Diving, follow [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54313/scuba-diving?referrer=0QXcCc3UynR7oPvcBbCDSg2), propose example questions, vote for other example questions, and get like-minded friends to do the same!

Comment: Well in diving, renting equipment is quite common, and I thought about something like `What equipment to use in extreem cold water?` or `... for diving in a shipwreck`. I think this will be on topic somewhere.

Comment: @Martin "What _kind_ of equipment", asking for the characteristics of the equipment, is OK. But asking for actual products isn't (unless you follow the guidelines in the linked blog post)